# Security of 2FA codes in-transit

Tags: multi-factor, totp

I work on a service that handles user authentication & authorization. I recently added 2FA support (email, sms, TOTP) and while it works great, I was wondering about the security of the one-time codes during transit (client->server request).

Assuming everything is going through HTTPS, does it make sense to encrypt/hash in the payload? I have seen some banking/financial systems doing it using some derivation technique (joining the code with another value, hashing the whole thing and only then sending, and the server would do the same).

Comment: If TLS is broken on that level, we have a multitude of problems. Your website is probably not very high on that list.

Comment: For this we can assume TLS is implemented correctly. Is TLS enough in that case? If so, why do banks etc add that hashing mechanism?

Comment: If TLS is broken, the attacker is free to modify the code that hashes things clientside.

Comment: Like I said, please assume TLS is not broken. Would additional security layer of hashing the code somehow help increase security?

Comment: In general banks can have archaic approaches to security that don't always make sense, either due to the tech involved or due to regulatory weirdness. Following in their footsteps, if you're not also a bank, is not a wise path.

Comment: Depends what you're describing on the banking side, but my understanding is that it's often a validation check to avoid mistakes e.g. typo in account details or accidentally adding an extra number to a payment amount.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If we assume TLS is not broken, then it doesn't really make sense to add obfuscation to transmit the OTP codes.

If we assume TLS is broken, it doesn't really make sense, as the Javascript transmitted to the client can be replaced by a MITM attack.

Comment: Could some kind of JS obfuscation potentially help against a passive MITM? In that case, the attacker could see the obfuscated OTPs but not use them themselves. Passive MITM could be more common, and might be the scenario to consider when this particular site isn't the one being targeted. Theoretically, it would still be completely broken, but could it help against a practical adversary?

Comment: @Danya02 I'm afraid someone can pick my very secure and certified front door lock. So I went to the store and bought either another lock of the same brand or a cheap uncertified lock of an unknown brand. I installed it. Is my front door more secure now? And even if you managed to protect the OTP, what about all the traffic of the user session that can be sniffed? You'll end up with a clumsy re-implementation of TLS or SRP.

Comment: I think the explanation should be one step more detailed than this. Since receiving the OTP via email or SMS is the weaker link compared to HTTPS, the service has to make sure the attacker can not authorize a transaction with just a single factor (only the OTP). But this is usually done by requiring a password to create a session, which can then use the OTP. So the browser is already sending two factors in a request: OTP and Session-key, and this is the reason we don't need a derived random value.

Comment: @Falco Irrelevant. The key point is that if we assume TLS to be secure, then we can trust it to protect *anything* from a third party. If we don't assume it to be secure, we can't achieve security when the *client software* is delivered over the very same - *unsecure* - channel. An attacker can simply remove whatever security you place in the client software. Delivery mechanism of OTP is irrelevant.

Comment: @Danya02 deobfuscation is pretty advanced, at best you're costing an attacker a day or two, which, if your service has any worth is irrelevant

Comment: @vidarlo in theory you are 100% right. But TLS does not exist in isolation, and the OP did not ask about the general security of TLS to transmit information, but asked if it there is any reason and value behind sending and hashing an additional value together with the OTP. - And yes, there is an additional benefit that has nothing to do with the security of TLS or in transit values, but with the weakness of sending the OTP over an insecure channel to the client and verifying that the same client which requested the OTP is also sending the reply. (This could also be done via session-pinning)

Comment: @Falco He asks about encryption/hashing in addition to TLS, not session pinning. He also explicitely asks about client to server, e.g. the path protected by TLS.

Comment: @vidarlo " have seen some banking/financial systems doing it using some derivation technique (joining the code with another value, hashing the whole thing and only then sending, and the server would do the same)." I think it is an oversight to think that the only reason for joining the OTP with another value and hashing is to encrypt it a second time. The "other value" is a shared secret between server and client, which is tied to the current session and will stop an attacker from using the OTP with a direct call to the API.

Answer (score 3):

It is a simple way of knowing that the browser that initiated the login process is the one that actually logged in.

Imagine that while the OTP is travelling to reach your phone, an adversary intercepts it and uses it to login to the target system.

If the OTP is associated with a random value that is sent to the browser that has initiated the login process, and instead of the OTP you send `hash(random value + OTP)` to the server, then just an intercepted OTP cannot be used from another browser because the random values (hence the hashes) won't match.

Simple but not bulletproof, though.

Comment: I'm providing JWT tokens that are signed, but marked as untrusted (lower level of permissions set in claims) after password is validated. It cannot be used to access the app, but can be replaced with actual token when correct OTP code is provided.
That would cover your scenario I believe, since the attacker would not have the untrusted token.

Comment: @GrzegorzJudas There's a window of opportunity between the point when the password is validated and when the OTP is validated. So, depending on how you handle the OTP verification when two login initiations from the same user take place at the (nearly) same time, you may or may not be affected by stolen OTPs (especially since you send it through email).

Comment: That's why best practice is *not* to trust SMS.